# Flex error 1120 (Access of undefined property XXX) when using constants in MXML

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

Again pulling my hair out due to some Flex/AS3 weirdness. The following code does not compile due to error 1120 - Access of undefined property AbstractWizardModel

```
<mx:HBox id="cntr_buttons" width="100%" horizontalAlign="right">
   <mx:Button label="{model.getButtonLabel(AbstractWizardModel.GO_BACK)}" />
</mx:HBox>
```

The constant is defined (in AbstractWizardModel) as:

```
[Bindable]
public class AbstractWizardModel extends EventDispatcher
{
   public static const GO_BACK : String = "goBack";
   ...
}
```

Replacing 'AbstractWizardModel.GO_BACK' with '"goBack"' does the trick, but what was the problem?

Thanks!

PS: Of course I am importing the AbstractWizardModel in the MXML code

Comment: Are you using Flash Builder 4 beta? I've noticed that imports frequently get stripped out of files due to some bugs that have yet to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man this is so weird..

I found kind of a solution, thanks to all comments, which helped me to get on the right track, but still think this is a bug in Flex.

First of all I have to add that (in my code) the MXML and AbstractWizardModel class are in the **same package**.

The 'getButtonLabel()' function that I am calling is declared as

```
[Bindable(event="getButtonLabelChanged")]
public function getButtonLabel (buttonId:String) : String
{
    ..
}
```

If I remove that [Bindable..] annotation, the code compiles.

If I leave it there, I have to add an import for class AbstractWizardModel, although it is in the same package. Anyway, that fixes the problem, too.

However :) FB4 removes that import everytime it organizes imports, so that user comment was helpful too.

Happy to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

The error is about the class AbstractWizardModel, not about the constant GO_BACK. You need to have an import statement for the class inside the mxml file:

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import the.package.AbstractWizardModel;
]]>
</mx:Script>
```

before you can use the class.
EDIT: replace "the.package." with whatever package the class is in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I had that import right from the start. Will edit my question to be more precise.

Comment: This is indeed weird AS3 behaviour.. The error message indicates that the class is unknown, which usually means that it is not imported or a needed swc is missing. Do you get any other warnings or errors?